# Indexing not working properly in DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

```
df
```

|  | Unnamed: 0 | Name | Age | Gender | Height |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | Asish | 20 | m | 5.11 |
| 1 | 1 | Meghali | 23 | f | 5.9 |
| 2 | 2 | Parimita | 49 | f | 5.6 |
| 3 | 3 | SatyaNarayan | 60 | m | 5.1 |

```
df.reset_index(drop=True,inplace=True)

df
```

|  | Unnamed: 0 | Name | Age | Gender | Height |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | Asish | 20 | m | 5.11 |
| 1 | 1 | Meghali | 23 | f | 5.9 |
| 2 | 2 | Parimita | 49 | f | 5.6 |
| 3 | 3 | SatyaNarayan | 60 | m | 5.1 |

```
df=df.reset_index(drop=True)

df
```

|  | Unnamed: 0 | Name | Age | Gender | Height |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | Asish | 20 | m | 5.11 |
| 1 | 1 | Meghali | 23 | f | 5.9 |
| 2 | 2 | Parimita | 49 | f | 5.6 |
| 3 | 3 | SatyaNarayan | 60 | m | 5.1 |

I have tried these above mentioned steps. However, they doesn't seem to resolve. I want something like below:

|  | Name | Age | Gender | Height |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Asish | 20 | m | 5.11 |
| 1 | Meghali | 23 | f | 5.9 |
| 2 | Parimita | 49 | f | 5.6 |
| 3 | SatyaNarayan | 60 | m | 5.1 |

Comment: When a question contains "*... is not working properly*", this usually means "*I do not understand...*".

Comment: Kind of right !! @mozway

Answer (score 2):

`Unnamed: 0` is not an index column. If you want to drop that:

`df.drop('Unnamed: 0', axis=1)`

Comment: Thank you soo much @Drach Noi, It worked out.

Answer (score 0):

If you're reading from CSV as hinted in your other question, the best might be to tell [`read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) that this first column is in fact the index:

```
df = pd.read_csv('your_file.csv', index_col=0)
```

And if you really have no use for the index in the CSV, do not have it in the first place.

When you initially save the file, do:

```
df.to_csv('your_file.csv', index=False)
```